# Error after I log in with my Google Account in Google Sheet API

Tags: java, maven, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to manipulate a Google Sheet through Java, but there's a error after I log in with my Google Account:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.esdras.caixaipm.DeskIPM.main(DeskIPM.java:75)
```

In this is my PSVM:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    sheetsService = getSheetsService();
    String range = "A2:A4";

    ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(SPREADSHEET_ID, range)
            .execute();

    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No data found!");
    }else{
        for (List row : values) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s \n", row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3));
        }
    }

}
```

I think the problem is in the for structure, but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I was getting was because of the "row.get()"

I edited the code to this:

```
for (List row : values) {
            System.out.println(row.get(0));
        }
```

Instead of:

```
for (List row : values) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s \n", row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3));
        }
```

Thanks... :)